# Energy flux formula

Tags: thermal-radiation, solar-system

I think that the energy flux is given by:

$$\text{G}=\mathcal{k}\cdot\text{T}^4\cdot\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{D}}\right)^2\tag1$$

Where $\mathcal{k}$ is the Boltzmann constant, $\text{T}$ is the surface temprature of the sun, $\text{R}$ is the radius of the sun and $\text{D}$ is the distance from the sun to the earth.

Now, for $\text{D}$ we know that is changes over a year because the earth makes a elliptical orbit around the sun.

> Question: Is my formula right?

Comment: $\frac{\pi R^2}{\pi D^2}$ is fine, however, the flux is not $k T^4$. Try to take total energy produced by the Sun instead of $k T^4$. Or include Sun surface.

Comment: Why don't you consult a textbook (Stefan-Boltzmann Law) before posting such a question here?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for sure has wrong units. [Usually](https://hesperia.gsfc.nasa.gov/sftheory/glossary.htm), energy flux has units of $\text{W} = \frac{\text{J}}{\text{s}}$, maybe $\frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}^2} = \frac{\text{J}}{\text{m}^2\text{s}}$.

The $G$ you define on the other hand has units of $\text{J}\text{K}^3$, which doesn't fit the standard unit definition.

You may be thinking about the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law), where for a blackbody we have 
$$
P = \sigma \cdot A\cdot T^4
$$
with $P$ the radiated power, $A$ the surface area, $T$ the temperature and $\sigma ={\frac  {2\pi ^{5}k^{4}}{15c^{2}h^{3}}}=5.670373\times 10^{{-8}}\,{\mathrm  {W\,m^{{-2}}K^{{-4}}}}$.

Comment: The units I need are $\text{W}/\text{m}^2$

Comment: @treq What are you trying to calculate? You are mentioning the sun and earth, so I assume you want to get to the Solar constant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant). In that case, just divide by $A$ in the Stefan-Boltzmann law.

Comment: The thing I mean is that: $$\text{G}=\sigma\cdot\text{T}^4\cdot\left(\frac{\text{R}_\text{sun}}{\frac{\text{p}}{1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta\right)}}\right)^2$$

Comment: Where I used kepler's law, is that correct? I try to calculate the sunconstant

Comment: @treq Yes, that is correct. Do you see that in your question you have written $k$ where it should be $\sigma$? The $\sigma$ is correct, as you can see by my and your formula.